# Apply a multiple to randomly selected months in a set of 12 months of revenue data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of revenue data for each month in a year in columns:

Month1=$304,161.68      Month2=$264,022.48      Month3=$231,374.13      Month4=$204,817.97      Month5=$183,216.61      Month6=$165,645.15      Month7=$151,351.41      Month8=$139,723.69      Month9=$130,264.49      Month10=$122,569.21     Month11=$116,308.76     Month12=$111,215.50

I also have a value in the same row that tells me how many of months in the year need to be considered "special" months. What I need to do is apply a multiple (also contained in the same row) to to each "special" month.

The determination of which months out of the 12 that are special must be random.

For example, say the "Number of special months" = 3. That means that 3 out of the 12 months of revenue above should have the multiplier applied. The 3 months must be randomly selected from the 12 available months and then each of those selected months must be multiplied by the multiple.

I've looked into Excel Solver, Excel Goal Seek, and Excel arrays but can't seem to figure out a solution.

Your Excel wizardry is greatly appreciated!

Peter

Answer (score 0):

To randomly choose 3 months, you can add a column to generate random numbers using:

```
=RAND()
```

then another column to choose the top 3 of those random numbers and apply your mulitplier where needed:

```
=IF(RANK(C1,$C$1:$C$12)<=3,A1*B1,A1)
```

I'm assuming here that the dollar values are in column A, the multipliers are in B, and my rand() formula is placed in column C.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I see what you're doing in your answer.

Comment: Sorry. Hit "post" by accident :). Can't seem to get a new line on my mobile. I'll try to clarify with a better explanation of the algorithm. Assume my revenue numbers are in an array called MonthlyRevenue. Line 1: generate 3 random integers between 1 and 12. Line 2: for i = each of the 3 randomly generated integers do: MonthlyRevenue[random integer i] = MontglyRevenue[random integer i] x multiple. (end of algorithm). The other issue I have is that the months are in columns not rows so I assume I have to create an array out of those columns somehow. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to show me what your data really looks like - maybe a screenshot. You are very limited here in the comments, but you can edit your question with lots of features.